# How to create a container with containerd instead of pulling it

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers, docker-registry, containerd

Im currently checking out containerd. Unfortunately the documentation is pretty sparse and you don’t find much on the Internet about it.

Im wondering if it is possible to create a new container from a Dockerfile or similar, just like `docker build` would work. The documentation only shows an example where the image is being pulled from a registry.

Id like to do that through the Go client not the `ctr` command line tool.

Comment: You're asking if something other than Docker is still Docker enough to use a `Dockerfile`? My guess is no since Docker exists and if you're using a `Dockerfile`, you're sort of stuck using Docker.

Comment: Remember, Docker containers can run in all kinds of non-Docker things, but building them is a Docker-specific process. There's also ways to build non-Docker containers that are compatible if they meet certain criteria.

Comment: @tadman containerd has been developed alongside of docker. And comtainerd does support pulling docker containers and running them.

Comment: @tadman containerd is just a more low level version of docker.

Comment: I think you misunderstand me. The container *runtime* has been standardized around Docker-type containers, lots of things can run them. The container *build environment* is not as diversified yet. People use Docker to build, but deploy it in all kinds of ways, containerd being one of them. There's lots of ways to build containerd-compatible containers, but if you're using a `Dockerfile`, I think you're stuck using Docker. Nothing else understands those.

Comment: @tadman I think you misunderstood me too, I don’t want to create a container in containerd that can be shared with docker. I want to create a container with containerd instead of pulling one and then run in with containerd. But maybe this isn’t even possible.

Comment: Well it might be possible, I don't know for sure, but I'm going to suggest that using a `Dockerfile` to do it isn't possible without Docker. There are other, older ways to build containers than Docker, so a container can be built, but it's going to use some method other than `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with BuildKit: https://github.com/moby/buildkit#containerd-image-store